# Java NIO Thread selector.select() Nullpointer

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, nio

I'm trying to implement a Java NIO Server in its own thread.

```
public class MyServer extends MyThread
{
   ServerSocketChannel server;
   Selector selector;

   public MyServer
   {
      super();
      this.server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
      this.server.configureBlocking(false);
      this.server.socket().bind(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 6666));
      this.selector = Selector.open();
      this.server.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
   }
   public void run()
   {
      while(true)
      {
          this.selector.select();
          Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
          Iterator<SelectionKey> i = keys.iterator();
          // Do channel work there
      }
   }
}
```

Problem is I'm getting a NullpointerException on this.selector.select(); in my run method.
Can you help me out? I don't see the issue.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace to the question.

Comment: Ok, I have it figured out. The problem was the constructor of my thread was running the thread before the server constructor finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the constructor of my thread was running the thread before the server constructor finished.

Thus a Nullpointer on the selector.